# Suppose $n$ is a natural number and $2^n-1$ is prime. Prove that $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ is perfect.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question that has been bothering me for a while. If anybody can help me solve this, it would take a great burden off my chest. Thank you very much!

Suppose $n$ is a natural number and $2^n-1$ is prime. Prove that $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ is perfect.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Theorem_of_Even_Perfect_Numbers

Comment: I'm not sure why there are two different proofs. Would you be able to explain to me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Because the statement goes backwards as well, you're interested in the first implication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of divisors of a number with prime factorization  $N=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ is $\sigma(N)=\frac{p_1^{a_1+1}-1}{p_1-1}\cdot \frac{p_2^{a_2+1}-1}{p_2-1}\cdots \frac{p_k^{a_k+1}-1}{p_k-1}$.
So here we obtain 
$$\sigma(N)=\sigma(2^{n-1}p)=\frac{2^n-1}{2-1}\cdot \frac{p^2-1}{p-1}=(2^{n}-1)(p+1)=p\cdot 2^n=2N $$
as desired.

Comment: Multiplicative function (+1) :)

Answer (score 2):

Euler's way: Define the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)$. It is easy to show that $\sigma(m n) = \sigma(m) \sigma(n)$ if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Now $n$ is perfect if $\sigma(n) = 2 n$.

Apply the above to $2^{n - 1} (2^n - 1)$
As $2^n - 1$ is prime, $\sigma(2^n - 1) = 2^n$:

$$
\sigma(2^{n - 1} (2^n - 1)) 
  = \sigma(2^{n - 1}) \cdot \sigma(2^n - 1)
  = \left( \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} 2^k \right) 2^n
  = \left( 2^n - 1 \right) \cdot 2^n
$$
Twice the number we started with.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the divisors of $2^{n-1} (2^n-1)$ is

$$(2 + 2^2 + \ldots+2^{n-2}) (2^n-1) = 2^{n-1} (2^n-1)$$

Comment: Thank you for the time to help me!